# PHP - Creating dependent dropdown lists

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have two dropdown lists which are populated with data from two seperate mysql tables connected with a foreign key, I was wondering am I able to make them dependent using php alone (without the use of ajax, jscript etc) other than by using a bunch of if statements on the second table?

so far I have:

```
   Movies:
   <select name="Movie">
   <option value="Pick a Movie">Pick a movie</option>
   <?php foreach($movies->fetchAll() as $movie):?>
   <option value="<?php echo $movie['id'];?>"> <?php echo 
  $movie['movietitle'];?> </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>

   Screening Time:
   <select name="times">
   <option value="Please select a Screening time">Please select a 
   screening time</option>
   <?php foreach($screenings->fetchAll() as $screening):?>
   <option value="<?php echo $screening['id'];?>"> <?php echo 
   $screening['time'];?> </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

My hope is that when a user selects a movie from the first dropdown menu, then only the screening times for that particular movie are displayed, as opposed to all screening times held in the db.

I assume that I need a foreign key to connect the two tables, so I now have two tables that are:

movies table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|           id        |    movietitle    |           
|---------------------|------------------|
|           1         |  pulp fiction    |           
|---------------------|------------------|
|           2         |    armageddon    |           
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     Titanic      |           
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Screening table

```
|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|           id        |  screening time     | courseid(fk)|
|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|           1         |     sun 11          |       3     |
|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|           2         |      sat 8          |       1     |
|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|          3          |       fri 9         |       2     |
|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|
```

so can am I able to tweak my code to include the courseid as a foreign key to make them dependent? if not is there any other way I can force a user to only be able to select certain groups of data in both menus i.e can select 
'titanic' 'friday 9' but not 'titanic' 'sun 11' or 'titanic' 'sat 8'?

Comment: Its not possible (well it wont be user friendly) with just php and html, why dont you want to use js?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a dependable dropdown you should need to make to dropdown and each dropdown will have separate **id**. Using change event you can continuously hit to the server. Then the server will respond to the request. After that, you will process the request and return the dropdown menu. 
You can make it inside while loop. You can see full code at [github website as reference](https://github.com/arif98741/dependable_dropdown_menu)

Follow below code and process

**index.php**

```
    <?php
if (file_exists('function.php')) {
    include_once 'function.php';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dependable Dropdown Menu</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                max-width: 600px;
            }
            .main{

                margin: 50px auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #country,#city{
                width: 500px;
                height: 50px;
                font-size: 18px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            select{
                width: 600px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
             <h1>Dependable Dropdown Menu</h1>
            <div class="dropdownmenu">
                <select name="" id="country" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php
                    $con = connection();
                    $stmt = $con->query("select * from country order by name");
                    if ($stmt) {
                        ?>
                        <?php while ($r = $stmt->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"><?php echo $r['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <select name="" id="city" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>   
        <script>
            $('#country').on('change', function () { //dropdown changing event
                var countryID = $(this).val(); //getting specific country id from database
                console.log(countryID);
                if (countryID !== '') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "fetch.php", //requesting to fetch.php for getting cities list as response
                        data: {// we are passing two values by get in the url
                            action: 'getcities',
                            countryid: countryID
                        },
                        method: 'get',
                        success: function (data) { //getting response from server
                            $('#city').html(data); //putting response to second dropdown
                            console.log(data);
                        }, error: function (e) { //this will show error if exist any
                            console.log(e); //for looking error message press ctrl+shift+i
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#city').html("<option>Select</option>");
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**fetch.php**

```
    <?php
if (file_exists('function.php')) {
    include_once 'function.php';
}
$con = connection();
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'getcities') {
    $countryid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['countryid']);
    $q = "select * from city where country='$countryid' order by name asc";
    $stmt = $con->query($q);
    $val = "";
    if ($stmt) {
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
                $val .= "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $val = "<option>Select</select>";
    }
    echo $val;
}
```

**function.php**

```
    <?php
//connection for project. this connection will be used in whole project
function connection() {
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'country_city');
    return $con;
}
```